# Cannot send message to Twitch chat or they wont display

Tags: c++, sockets, irc, twitch

I want to create a bot, just for my curiosity. And i want to send message to Twitch chat, but I can connect, join a channel, but when i send message nothing is display on Twitch Chat. And my `send` doesn't return an error, so i don't understand.

```
bool IrcBot::sendData(std::string msg) {//Envoie des donnees
    int len = msg.length();
    int bytes_sent = send(s, msg.c_str(), len, 0);
    cout << "Data sent : " << msg;

    if (bytes_sent == -1 || bytes_sent == 0) {
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Where `msg` = `PRIVMSG #channel :Test\r\n`

Comment: Could you try to log the msg and see what it says?

Comment: I forgot i ask a question, i don't know the real problem but after a couple day, and after the validation of account for my bot, it's just start to work. But i don't know why.

Comment: Haha alright be sure to close the question if it's solved unless you are still curious as to why it didn't work.

Comment: Actually I have the same problem, this post might help me :D